# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "products" does not exist

Tags: java, database, postgresql, jpa, orm

I'm working on the following code:

***Product***

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "products",
 public class Product extends RepresentativeModel {
 @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "products", targetEntity = Category.class)
 private Set<Category> categories = new HashSet<>();
 }
```

***Category***

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "categories",
 public class Category extends RepresentativeModel {
 @ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "productToCategory",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "categoryId")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "productId")})
private Set<Product> products = new HashSet<>();
 }
```

***EM config***

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(@Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource source) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(source);
    entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.x.model");
    JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
    entityManagerFactory.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties());
    entityManagerFactory.setPersistenceUnitName(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
    log.debug("PERSISTENCE UNIT " + PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
    return entityManagerFactory;
}
```

***Package info***

package is `com.x.model` for both

```
Properties properties = new Properties(); 
properties.put("hibernate.default_schema", "public"); 
entityManagerFactory.setJpaProperties(properties);
```

---

**Problem**

Products tables exists in the database, but I'm getting this error message:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "products" does not
>   exist

I tried to change entity name to "*products*" or to change `mappedBy` to "*Product*", but without success.

How to fix this?

Comment: Try to give another name to your `Set<Product> products` (and change the `mappedBy` accordingly).

Comment: thx!! changed both to products2, fails still with "products" in error, so problem is not with mapping, any ideas?

Comment: Double check that your table is called `products` and not e.g `product` .

Comment: it is products.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem, and all the answers in internet did not help me. And I find out that postrgres creates tables in case sensitive manner, if you add double quotes when creating tables.

```
"auteur" and auteur are two different names.
```

I don’t know exactly how it works, but apparently Hibernate cannot find the `@JoinTable` for the `@ManyToMany` relation, because, as I wrote above, this is a different table for postgres. Knowing this solved my problem. Maybe this will help someone else.